# Checking for convertability at runtime in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

In c++ different type conversions are implicitly done. For example an object of type `int` can be assigned to `const int` (as done in the first lines of the main function in the code below).

Now I would like to check for convertability at runtime in the sence that I have a structure where I can add types and later I want to check for a given type if one of the types stored in the structure is convertible to the given type.

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct bar { virtual void dummy() {} };
template<typename T> struct foo : public bar { virtual void dummy() {} };

int main() {

    int i1 = 1;
    const int i2 = i1;

    std::vector<bar*> bars;
    bar* t1 = new foo<int>; bars.push_back(t1);
    bar* t2 = new foo<int const>; bars.push_back(t2);

    foo<int const>* t3 = dynamic_cast<foo<int const>*>(bars[0]);
    std::cout << t3 << std::endl;

    foo<int const>* t4 = dynamic_cast<foo<int const>*>(bars[1]);
    std::cout << t4 << std::endl;

    delete t1;
    delete t2;

    return 0;
}
```

In order to store types in a structure I created the templated structure `foo` which is derived from `bar`. Then I can store the different types `int` and `int const` (to be precise pointers to objects of type `foo<int>` and `foo<int const>`) in a vector of `bar*`s. Then for a given type (here `int const`) I check for each element in this vector if it could be dynamically casted to a `foo` with this type.

When running this code `t3` becomes the `nullptr` and `t4` a non-null pointer. But I wanted to have for `t3` also a non-null pointer.

I hope it became approximately clear what I want to do.

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this kind of checking for comvertability at runtime (a solution involving c++11-features would be totally fine)?

Comment: Ah, double dispatch.  We meet again.

Comment: If you know and are ok with listing all possible conversions at compile time, this is possible.  Otherwise, it's not really possible

Comment: My first reaction was: Use `std::is_convertible<From, To>::value` but for some reason I get that `std::is_convertible<int const, int>::value` is true (why?).

Comment: Wait, do you want to support _any_ conversions, only compiler conversions, or just const/volatile conversions?

Comment: @alfC: because `const int` _is_ convertible to `int`...

Comment: @MooingDuck, right, I figured out, I had to use pointers, see my answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I would like to support as much as possible from section 4 "Standard conversions" from the c++ standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, since `foo<int>` and `foo<const int>` are completely unrelated types, you can't do this easily.

```
bar* t1 = new foo<int>;
foo<int const>* t3 = ?????<foo<int const>*>(t1);
```

`t3` can't be a pointer at any part of `t1`, since `t1` neither is, nor contains, a `foo<int const>` for `t3` to point at.  The only way to get any sort of good behavior out of this is to make a *copy* of the data that `t1` holds into a brand new `foo<int const>*`.  This frustrating limitation is a side-effect of templates being specializable with unrelated types, which is an awesomely powerful tool, but results in this confusion.  A general rule of thumb is to NOT put const/volatile qualifications, nor references of any sort into template parameters, unless that is the *sole* reason for the template class (such as `std::remove_reference`).

However, I just realized, what you want is for `foo<int>` and for `foo<const int>` to be the same type(ish), and *that* can be done (sortof)!

```
struct base { 
    virtual ~base(){}; //always have virtual destructor with polymorphism
    virtual void dummy()=0; //pure virtual, forces override
};
template<typename T> 
struct foo : public bar { 
    virtual void dummy() {} 
};
template<typename T> struct foo<const T> : public foo<T> {};
template<typename T> struct foo<volatile T> : public foo<T> {};
template<typename T> struct foo<const volatile T> : public foo<T> {};


base* t1 = new derived<const int>;
derived<int>* t3 = dynamic_cast<derived<int>*>(t1); //hooray!
//you can go from derived<const int> to derived<int> but not the other way around
```

Comment: This looks interesting. In your code it only supports cv-qualifiers but I think I can extend it at least to a somewhat bigger subset of the standard type-conversions. Am I correct, that the third line with const volatile is not actually needed as otherwise we would simply have a two-step inheritance a la `foo<T const volatile> is a foo<T const> is a foo<T> (is a base)`?

Comment: Though it doesn't do exactly I was hoping for I take this as the accepted answer. It seems (in an extended version) to be the closest I can get.

Answer (score -1):

Use `std::is_convertible<From*, To*>::value`

```
#include<type_traits>
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    cout << std::is_convertible<int const, int>::value << endl; // print true
    cout << std::is_convertible<int const*, int*>::value << endl; // print false
    cout << std::is_convertible<int const, int>::value << endl; // print true
    cout << std::is_convertible<std::string, int>::value << endl; // print false
    cout << std::is_convertible<std::string*, int*>::value << endl; // print false
}
```

Note that you have to use the pointer type to obtain the excepted behavior with respect to `const`ness for example.

(I guess in C++98 you can do the same with `boost::is_convertible`.)

Comment: And how would you apply this to a polymorphic template like in the question?

Comment: Well, I didn't understand that part of the question, I assumed that once you have access to the conversion at runtime and compile time you can do whatever you want with it, including dispatch, double dispatch and compile-time dispatch, `enable_if`, etc.

Comment: The conversions are _easy_.  What he wants is for `foo<int>` and `foo<const int>` to be the same type.

Comment: I see, then yes he is asking that `foo<const int>` is derived from `foo<int>` (as in your answer). Well, I think it still answers part of the question (the title at least).

Comment: @alfC: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know that there is a std::is_convertible. But it seems that it doesn't solve my problem since all types need to be known at compile time.

Comment: @maikg, that I don't understand, do you need to know if a type is convertible into another type at compile time and at runtime, right? `is_convertible<,>::value` is a compile-time constant and also a runtime constant.

Comment: @alfC: Well, I would like to put different things into the From-part and at compile time I don't know which exactly...